# Assistance with Python multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Currently, i have a list of url to grab contents from and is doing it serially. I would like to change it to grabbing them in parallel. This is a psuedocode. I will like to ask is the design sound? I understand that .start() starts the thread, however, my database is not updated. Do i need to use q.get() ? thanks

```
import threading    
import Queue
q = Queue.Queue()

def do_database(url):
    """ grab url then input to database """
    webdata = grab_url(url)
    try:
        insert_data_into_database(webdata)
    except:
        ....
    else:
        < do I need to do anything with the queue after each db operation is done?>

def put_queue(q, url ):
    q.put( do_database(url) )

for myfiles in currentdir:
    url = myfiles + some_other_string
    t=threading.Thread(target=put_queue,args=(q,url))
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()
```

Comment: Make sure you commit the transaction in your `insert_data_into_database` function otherwise nothing will get written.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, database is working fine, as i mention i have been doing it serially. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's odd that you're putting stuff into `q` but never taking anything out of `q`.  What is the purpose of `q`?  In addition, since `do_database()` doesn't `return` anything, sure looks like the only thing `q.put(do_database(url))` does is put `None` into `q`.

The usual way these things work, a description of work to do is added to a queue, and then a fixed number of threads take turns pulling things off the queue.  You probably don't want to create an unbounded number of threads ;-)

Here's a pretty complete - but untested - sketch:

```
import threading
import Queue

NUM_THREADS = 5  # whatever

q = Queue.Queue()
END_OF_DATA = object()  # a unique object

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            url = q.get()
            if url is END_OF_DATA:
                break
            webdata = grab_url(url)
            try:
                # Does your database support concurrent updates
                # from multiple threads?  If not, need to put
                # this in a "with some_global_mutex:" block.
                insert_data_into_database(webdata)
            except:
                #....

threads = [Worker() for _ in range(NUM_THREADS)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for myfiles in currentdir:
    url = myfiles + some_other_string
    q.put(url)

# Give each thread an END_OF_DATA marker.
for _ in range(NUM_THREADS):
    q.put(END_OF_DATA)

# Shut down cleanly.  `daemon` is way overused.
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: hi, the purpose of q, is to just put each task into it. ok, so i do need to take it out after each task in completed. thanks for your sketch. will try to understand.

Comment: Well, the `q` in **my** code holds the URLs you want to fetch.  In your code, you're **calling** `do_database(url)`, and putting the **result** of that call into your `q`.  There's a big difference ;-)

Comment: yes, i understand. I have slight confusion on the the put() works.

Comment: I expect the most important thing you can get from my code is how to tell the threads there's no more work to do (the `END_OF_DATA` dance).  If you just have a bunch of daemon threads, and let the main program end, all your threads will die abruptly, regardless of what they're doing.  The `END_OF_DATA` dance here lets each thread **know** when there's no more to be done, and then the main program waits for them to end (`.join()`s them all before exiting).

Comment: wow, thanks. i incorporated your sketch and it works. excellent! now i can understand more on this topic. cheers

Comment: Oops!  The `run()` method needed a `self` argument - I repaired that.

I think you'll be happy with this.  As others have said, there are several other fancy frameworks for dealing with this kind of thing, but threads work fine for I/O-bound tasks (which this is - under the covers you'll be spending most of your time waiting for sockets to receive data).  Have fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should do this with asynchronous programming rather than threads.  Threading in Python is problematic (see: Global Interpreter Lock), and anyway you're not trying to achieve multicore performance here.  You just need a way to multiplex potentially long-running I/O.  For that you can use a single thread and an event-driven library such as [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Twisted comes with HTTP functionality, so you can issue many concurrent requests and react (by populating your database) when results come in.  Be aware that this model of programming may take a little getting used to, but it will give you good performance if the number of requests you're making is not astronomical (i.e. if you can get it all done on one machine, which it seems is your intention).

Comment: thanks, i don't think i want to install another library, as what i want to do is rather simple. Getting a bunch of urls and inserting into database "at the same time", instead of going through a loop one by one. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For DB, You have to commit before your changes become effective. But, commit for every insert is not optimal. Commit after bulk changes gives much better performance.

For parallel, Python isn't born for this. For your use-case, i suppose using python with gevent would be a painless solution.

Here is a much more efficient pseudo implementation FYI:

```
import gevent
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
patch_all() # to use with urllib, etc
from gevent.queue import Queue


def web_worker(q, url):
  grab_something
  q.push(result)

def db_worker(q):
  buf = []
  while True:
    buf.append(q.get())
    if len(buf) > 20:
      insert_stuff_in_buf_to_db
      db_commit
      buf = []

def run(urls):
  q = Queue()
  gevent.spawn(db_worker, q)
  for url in urls:
    gevent.spawn(web_worker, q, url)


run(urls)
```

plus, since this implementation is totally single threaded, you can safely manipulate shared data between workers like queue, db connection, global variables etc.